# Vivaldi Antenna: size & max input power & software simulation

Tags: antenna, simulation

First, I've to say I'm a beginner in this field so please forgive me if my questions were not smart.

I was reading about Vivaldi antenna and I decided to do an experiment; I'm going to use a flat sheet of copper tape, a piece of FR4, and a coaxel cable.

I have the following two questions:

- What is the impact of changing the size of the antenna?
- What specifies the maximum input power namely in this experiment?
- Is there a software that I can use to model & simulate the antenna accurately?

Comment: Question: at what frequencies are you planning to use this? How much RF power do you have available?

Comment: Frequency: 2.4-5GHz. Max power available 3000W.

Comment: I don't think there is any cable that can carry that much power continuously, you'll need a waveguide. Perhaps it could be done for a pulse, for radar etc.  What is the source of the power?

Comment: I plan to test it in a rural farm to extend wifi range. The power will be drawn from a standard outlet.

Comment: Fabio you need to do a lot more reading. Wifi is 0.1 or 0.2 W, perhaps 1 or 2 W with a booster (not legal in most countries). 3000 W is a quarter of a million dollar problem, not something you will use for farm wifi. The Vivaldi isn't suitable - it is broad band but quite low gain; Google for the Cantenna for an easy-to-build wifi antenna to extend your range.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Cantenna seems exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the Vivaldi will determine the lowest frequency that it works at.

The input power will probably be limited by the coaxial cable. With a high power cable on a small antenna, you might find that the PCB overheats in the feed region.

There is modelling software but it's not cheap ($10,000 -  $100,000), and not easy to learn. Try a demo of FEKO, it converts to a free Lite version which is limited but could just about model a basic planar Vivaldi.

Comment: What factors contribute to the overheat of the cable & PCB?

Comment: I mean when I buy a cable & a PCB, what specifications should I look at to estimate the overheat issue?